# Invalid default value null for timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp, mysql-error-1064, create-table, mysql-5.6

my database is mySql 5.6.48. Invalid default value for 'modify_time' Error occur during I excute the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `check_wave_status`  (
  `com_uid` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `modify_time` timestamp(0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`com_uid`, `wave_uid`, `trade_uid`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `idx_modify_time`(`com_uid`, `modify_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

,My sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,How can I correct this error?

Comment: What do you mean by `TIMESTAMP(0)` instead of just `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: timestamp(p), where p is the number of digits in the fractional part of second (microseconds).With 0 there are no fractions of the second.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

there is no default NULL for timestamps in mysql

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `NOT NULL` instead of `DEFAULT NULL`. The first `TIMESTAMP` column is auto-populated.